# Buildroot: running Lighttpd

Tags: linux, lighttpd, beagleboard, buildroot

I'm trying to get Lighttpd up and running, but I'm having a few issues and
wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction.  I've only delt
with Apache2, which was a breeze to get up and running on my Ubuntu box, but
I need a server in a new build on my BeagleBoard-xm and thought Lighttpd
would be worth trying so I added all the dependencies and rebuilt it.  After
building I brought the system back up and can only find the lighttpd and
lighttpd-angel in the /usr/sbin/ and a library of mods in
usr/lib/lighttphd/.  Running lighttpd returns "No configuration available.
Try using -f option.".  Is the config file is somewhere here and I can't
find it, do I need to create one, or is it lost to the methos?  I was assuming I would get something
under /etc/ as well, but no lighttpd folder there.  Like I said I've not
done this before and need a good poke in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried lighttpd but it seems like there is no default configuration to run it. There is a documentation at http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/TutorialConfiguration which you can find config file to run the server and command line arguments.

However, I recommend you to user thttpd (http://acme.com/software/thttpd/). It is very lightweight and fast. It doesn't need so much configuration. You could build and run it easily.

Comment: I did look at http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/TutorialConfiguration but came up with errors (i think missing files).  I'll give thttpd a try, the more lightweight the better for an embedded right?  I'll try it and see how it goes, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Edit:  Builds great!  Buildroot has it already, all I had to do was point it to my build tools and change output/build/thttpd-2.25b/extras/passwd.c's use of getline with get_line (conflict with another predefined) and it built right up.  I get all the right files in my new rootfs: /var/www, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, etc...  I'll probably still have some teathing issues, but that's too be expected.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the config file yourself and run lighthttpd with the -f option to let it know where to find it (although if I remember it will look y default in /etc).

If I remember correctly there is a sample config file in the lighthttpd source distributions.